# Using Selenium in Python with Firefox, driver.close() takes over a second to execute

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, optimization, delay

I'm running code that will open a page in Firefox, go to another and then close. This all runs on a loop. Opening the browser (i.e. `driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)` takes 10~15 seconds which is annoying enough, but two out of every three iterations `driver.close()` takes ~70 seconds to execute, but only takes 3~5 seconds otherwise.

I've run this test both while browsing the internet normally and with all other applications closed. Are there any ways to fix this?

I have a text file with 110 tests from my recent run: if I just print out the first twenty loops here for example:

```
    1. Total time: 97.49061679840088. Driver init time: 22.793721199035645. Driver close time: 70.56271457672119
    2. Total time: 29.890846967697144. Driver init time: 21.84219241142273. Driver close time: 5.050010681152344
    3. Total time: 83.76592326164246. Driver init time: 12.503604173660278. Driver close time: 68.3823926448822
    4. Total time: 83.09610056877136. Driver init time: 11.358891010284424. Driver close time: 68.82680892944336
    5. Total time: 85.59329676628113. Driver init time: 12.615221738815308. Driver close time: 68.96531939506531
    6. Total time: 86.16180109977722. Driver init time: 14.600278377532959. Driver close time: 68.67035222053528
    7. Total time: 21.598666191101074. Driver init time: 15.27049446105957. Driver close time: 3.7224440574645996
    8. Total time: 21.767667531967163. Driver init time: 15.962707281112671. Driver close time: 3.6543126106262207
    9. Total time: 84.4701280593872. Driver init time: 11.948349714279175. Driver close time: 69.67394542694092
    10. Total time: 82.64682197570801. Driver init time: 11.970864295959473. Driver close time: 68.08720850944519
    11. Total time: 16.7623507976532. Driver init time: 10.733571767807007. Driver close time: 2.8674981594085693
    12. Total time: 80.45756483078003. Driver init time: 10.312459945678711. Driver close time: 67.43673586845398
    13. Total time: 19.663820028305054. Driver init time: 12.692358016967773. Driver close time: 3.613187551498413
    14. Total time: 80.84877896308899. Driver init time: 10.681751251220703. Driver close time: 67.37417578697205
    15. Total time: 81.78451681137085. Driver init time: 11.500747203826904. Driver close time: 67.31524991989136
    16. Total time: 80.11573123931885. Driver init time: 10.158656597137451. Driver close time: 67.29093480110168
    17. Total time: 79.48327779769897. Driver init time: 9.645284175872803. Driver close time: 67.29878664016724
    18. Total time: 17.019368171691895. Driver init time: 11.569543838500977. Driver close time: 2.676997661590576
    19. Total time: 16.036169290542603. Driver init time: 10.342987537384033. Driver close time: 2.6465227603912354
    20. Total time: 79.30259871482849. Driver init time: 10.23939561843872. Driver close time: 66.33623743057251
```

Thanks to all in advance. I use `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "XPATH"))).click()` to navigate the browser, if that helps.

Comment: How are you calculating `init time` and `close time`

Comment: I'm using time.time() on either side of driver.get("https://...") for the init time and again on either side of driver.close(). Thanks for commenting.